# Replace parts of filename (timestamp)

Tags: excel, vba

I have trouble when saving a new filename with timestamp
then it just puts in a new timestamp.

how can i replace the current timestamp in the name with the new one?

my filename goes from "28-11-2018 XXXXXXX" to "29-11-2018 28-11-2018 XXXXXX"

here is my code:

```
Sub workbook_save()
Dim thisWb As Workbook
Set thisWb = ActiveWorkbook
MyOldName = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
MyNewName = Format(Now, "dd-mm-yyyy") & " " & ActiveWorkbook.Name

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=thisWb.Path & "\" & MyNewName
Kill MyOldName
End Sub
```

thanks in advance

Comment: You can use a separator like " _ " to split the name in two parts , 1) date 2) workbook name , so in the next run you can split the name and replace the first part.

Comment: But how do i Replace? :)

Comment: Is the _XXXXXX_ part static text or does that change each day as well?  It would be hard to use `Replace` on the time part as that would change each time.  If _X_ doesn't change you can use `NewName = Format(Now,"dd-mm-yyyy_hhmmss") & "XXXXX.XLSM"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

In fixfilename put the "XXXXXX" part of your filename which I assume is a static value.

```
Sub workbook_save()
Dim thisWb As Workbook
Dim fixfilename As String
Dim newfilename As String
Set thisWb = ActiveWorkbook

fixfilename = "TESTFILE"
newfilename = Format(Now, "dd-mm-yyyy") & fixfilename
thisWb.SaveAs Filename:=thisWb.Path & "\" & newfilename
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`Format(Now, "dd-mm-yyyy")` you are saving your file simply as dd-mm-yyyy - there is no output of hours, minutes, seconds in your file name, change the date format to dd-mm-yyyy hhmmss000.

Comment: The X's is just for example text :) i just want the file name to ONLY have one set of date! :)